# Установка библиотек Spring на сервер

Tags: java, ubuntu, spring, spring-mvc

Каждый раз когда мне надо обновить Spring приложение, мне необходимо закачивать на сервер файл размером 30 мегабайт, 29 из которых занимают библиотеки spring. Можно ли как нибудь установить все библиотеки на сервер, чтобы загружать непосредственно свой код размером 1 мегабайт ?

Comment: Используйте `maven` или `gradle` и не изобретайте велосипед.

Comment: @Tsyklop Maven как раз таки вшивает все библиотеки в jar файл, и его целиком приходится грузить на сервер

Comment: Так и что Вам не подходит тогда? Настройте `CD` для автоматического деплоймента,

Comment: @Tsyklop просто библиотеки одни и те же, зачем их каждый раз в jar файл упаковывать, разве нельзя как нибудь на сервере их установить ?

Comment: Можно на сервере сложить все в какую-то папку и при запуске приложения указывать в `class path` путь к этим библиотекам. Но не забудете ли Вы обновить версию библиотеки на сервере? в мавене то это делается легко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть как минимум два варианта решения этой задачи:

#### Настройка Maven Dependency Plugin

Смысл действий сводится к [копированию всех зависимостей](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) в отдельную директорию при сборке. В `pom.xml` для этого потребуется примерно такая конфигурация:

```xml
<project>

    <!-- прочие настройки проекта -->

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>
                                ${project.build.directory}/libs
                            </outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Для уточнения списка копируемых зависимостей можно использовать свойства, начинающиеся на `include` и `exclude` в блоке `configuration`.

После сборки проекта в директории `target` появится директория `libs`, в которой будут все зависимости проекта. Но в этом случае в одной директории с JAR проекта должна находиться директория `libs` с зависимостями (подробности в META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` собранного JAR). JAR проекта и зависимости можно будет обновлять отдельно от друг от друга.

Обращаю внимание на то, что `spring-boot-maven-plugin` не должен быть настроен на сборку толстого JAR.

#### Использование `spring-boot-thin-layout`

Второй вариант - использование `spring-boot-thin-layout` в качестве зависимости для `spring-boot-maven-plugin`.

В этом случае `pom.xml` будет иметь такую конфигурацию:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot.experimental</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-thin-layout</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.23.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

При запуске проекта, собранного с такой конфигурацией, зависимости будут подтянуты автоматически в стандартную директорию для репозитория Maven (`~/.m2/repository`), и приложение будет в дальнейшем использовать их.

Подробно можно почитать [тут](https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-boot-thin-launcher) и [тут](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-thin-jar).